# to find extreme points, which loop is better?

Tags: c++

Assume we have a set of points with `(x,y)` coordinates. I am trying to find `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, `maxY` without sorting.

So, what I want to know is if there is any speed difference between these two ways.

**Approach 1**

```
minX = minY = maxX = maxY = points[0];
for(int i = 1 ; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if(minX > points[i].x)
    {
        minX = points[i].x;
    }
    if(minY > points[i].y)
    {
        minY = points[i].y;
    }
    if(maxX < points[i].x)
    {
        maxX = points[i].x;
    }
    if(maxY < points[i].y)
    {
        maxY = points[i].y;
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
minX = minY = maxX = maxY = points[0];
for(int i = 1 ; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if(minX > points[i].x)
    {
        minX = points[i].x;
    }
}
for(int i = 1 ; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if(minY > points[i].y)
    {
        minY = points[i].y;
    }
}
for(int i = 1 ; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if(maxX < points[i].x)
    {
        maxX = points[i].x;
    }
}
for(int i = 1 ; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if(maxY < points[i].y)
    {
        maxY = points[i].y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try measuring them?

Comment: Don't forget to turn on optimizations before you measure.  Measuring non optimized code really isn't useful.

Comment: The only reliable way to find out is to measure them. My guess is the first loop will be better, since it has better cache affinity, however it might also depend on compiler and processor architecture.

Comment: @NathanOliver How to turn on optimizations?

Comment: Depends on the compiler/IDE and how you compile it.  If you are using g++ or clang then you want to use the `-O2` or `-O3` flags.  If you have MSVS then you want to run the code in release mode.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting that they are not *quite* equivalent due to `i` starting at 1 in the first case - the behaviour of the second case looks *undefined* to me as you appear to be reading uninitialised data - plump for the first case. It's easier to read, and *probably* faster as it will execute fewer statements, *assuming no compiler optimisations*.

The first case is also easier to *maintain*. In fixing the undefined behaviour of the second case, you need to change 4 loops.

Although do consider using `std::minmax_element` for readability and bin the explicit looping entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of Bathsheba's suggestion to make use of [`minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element), I wanted to provide an example of it's use in this scenario.

```
const auto xMinMaxPair = std::minmax_element(std::begin(points), std::end(points), [](auto const& a, auto const& b)
{
    return (a.x < b.x);
});

const auto yMinMaxPair = std::minmax_element(std::begin(points), std::end(points), [](auto const& a, auto const& b)
{
    return (a.y < b.y);
});
```

It is up to you to determine if it is more appropriate for your uses. But it is always nice to have more options to choose from.

An example of it being used is below (you can [see it running here](http://ideone.com/AXAqpz)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
    Point(float const px = 0.0f, float const py = 0.0f)
        : x{ px }, y{ py }
    {

    }

    float x;
    float y;
};

void FindMinMaxPoint(std::vector<Point> const& points, Point& xMinMax, Point& yMinMax)
{
    const auto xMinMaxPair = std::minmax_element(std::begin(points), std::end(points), [](auto const& a, auto const& b)
    {
        return (a.x < b.x);
    });

    const auto yMinMaxPair = std::minmax_element(std::begin(points), std::end(points), [](auto const& a, auto const& b)
    {
        return (a.y < b.y);
    });

    xMinMax.x = xMinMaxPair.first->x;
    xMinMax.y = xMinMaxPair.second->x;

    yMinMax.x = yMinMaxPair.first->y;
    yMinMax.y = yMinMaxPair.second->y;
}

int main()
{
    auto points = std::vector<Point>{};

    points.push_back({ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    points.push_back({ 3.0f, 2.0f });
    points.push_back({ 8.0f, 0.0f });
    points.push_back({ 5.0f, 7.0f });

    auto xMinMax = Point{ };
    auto yMinMax = Point{ };

    FindMinMaxPoint(points, xMinMax, yMinMax);

    std::cout << "Min X: " << xMinMax.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max X: " << xMinMax.y << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Min Y: " << yMinMax.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max Y: " << yMinMax.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```